# Driver' door locking/unlocking problem

Tags: accord

I found out that the driver's side of my Honda Accord could not be locked or unlocked with key either manually or remotely. what could be responsible for this?

Comment: Can you hear relays switching when you press the key? If you can, I'd look at something mechanical, such as a push rod actuator inside the door which may have come loose. Of course, to get to the actuator, you probably need to open the door... Catch-22.

Comment: What year Honda Accord????